# Setting default value in FileGDB table column during GDAL/ogr2ogr export from PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, gdal, export, file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr

I'm doing an export for one table (table name: 'schaden_polygon') from a PostGIS-database (db-name: 'mydata') to ESRI FileGDB via ogr2ogr commandline-tool. The PostGIS-table contains a column 'm_uuid' [where uuid is automatically generated via 'uuid_generate_v1()']. After the export, the default value in the FileGDB column 'm_uuid' is set to "*uuid_generate_v1()*", which causes trouble in further data processing. This happens since GDAL-update to version 2.0.
I'm wondering if there is any possibility to set the default value to NULL during the export-process by using ogr2ogr commandline-tool. I'm using the following commandline for the PostGIS to FileGDB-Conversion

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\ogr2ogr -f "FileGDB" D:\data_export.gdb PG:"host=192.168.0.74 port=5432 user=postgres dbname=mydata password=postgres" schaden_polygon
```